# VBA dynamic range for formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I've posted a snippet of my code below. My actual workbook has a lot more formulas, but they are all structured like the formulas below. The amount of data I'm working with can change on a month to month basis, so I never know how many rows I will need the formulas to carry down. My little cheat for this was to make the destination range for all the formulas **"XX2:XX500"**, because there will never be more than 500 rows.

```
'November Remaining Spending Plan
 Range("BF2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-43]+RC[-40]+RC[-37]+RC[-34]+RC[-31]+RC[-28]+RC[-25]+RC[-22])"
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BF2:BF500")

'December Remaining Spending Plan
 Range("BG2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-41]+RC[-38]+RC[-35]+RC[-32]+RC[-29]+RC[-26]+RC[-23])"
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BG2:BG500")
```

I would like to make the range dynamic so I can remove the

```
"IF(RC[-1]="""","""","
```

part of the formula and having the extra formulas in the workbook isn't ideal for pivot tables and other users.

I've tried playing with the ranges using combinations of LastRow, FillDown, CurrentRegion, but I haven't had any luck.

Each formula should have the same amount of rows as all other formulas and the amount of formulas should always equal the number of rows in column A minus 1 (the minus 1 is for the header).

Is there a way to clean this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Always set the parent of all Range Objects
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'This should be called by name: Worksheets("Sheet1")

' this assumes column "A" is the column which sets the lastrow.
'If a different column sets the end of the dataset change "A" to that column
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'do not use .Select or .Activate it slows the code
'You do not need autofill just put it in all the cells at once


'November Remaining Spending Plan
 ws.Range("BF2:BF" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-43]+RC[-40]+RC[-37]+RC[-34]+RC[-31]+RC[-28]+RC[-25]+RC[-22]"

'December Remaining Spending Plan
 ws.Range("BG2:BG" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "RC[-41]+RC[-38]+RC[-35]+RC[-32]+RC[-29]+RC[-26]+RC[-23]"
```

Comment: This is great - thanks! One more question for you, how do I make it so I can use "Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As WorksheetSet ws = ActiveSheet Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row" across other modules? Is there a way to set this to public? If it can't be used in other modules, I can just move formulas all into one module. Right now my formulas with range X2:XX500 are in multiple modules.

Comment: just make a public variable.  On top of one the module put `Public lastrow as Long`  Then in the sub remove the `Dim lastrow as Long`.  Then you set it once and while Excel is open and you do not use `End` by itself in any code.  It will maintain the value and can be called and used by other modules.

Comment: This is what I have now and it's not picking up in other modules. `'On Top of Module 1
Public LastRow As Long
'In Module 1 where variable is defined
Sub VariableTest()`

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Test")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

And then I have the calculations in the second module. `'Calculation in Module 2
Sub Test()

'New Nov Rem Est
ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[1]"

End Sub`

Comment: At this point since it is hard to format code in comments, please ask a new question, with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are refreshing data monthly and need to have formulas in the columns to the right of the data.  The issue is how to determine which rows to put formulas in.  Short answer is put code into the ThisWorkBook!Workbook_Open() sub to delete the range from row BF2 to BG500 (since that's the max range), then copy the formula from row 2 to the number of rows that you have data in.  You mentioned LastRow so I assume you know how to do this.  Do you need sample code or is this enough to get you started?